# Unable import package

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I'm trying to import the Mainpage as package like I  always do but I can't. I don't understand why bcs it works all the time. This is what it said when I click view problem

> The method 'MainPage' isn't defined for the type 'MyApp'.
> Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'MainPage'.dartundefined_method

This is the code

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized;
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: MainPage (),
    );
   }
 }
```

I also try with other words like LoginPage, but it still don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't create a dart file called ‍**MainPage**. You must first create a **MainPage**.

**You create a dart file named MainPage, then **import** that file to the main page.**

Answer (score 0):

You probably did not create a HomePage widget.
You can fix it by creating it.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: MainPage(), //No error here
    );
  }
}

class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MainPage> createState() => _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(body: Center(child: Text("Hello World")));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you created the MainPage on the very same file? If not, you are missing the MainPage file import at the start, something like:

`import 'package:your_app/maybe_a_folder/your_file_that_contains_main_page.dart';`

Answer (score -1):

`home: MainPage(),` instead of `home: MainPage (),`

remove space between MainPage and function brackets `()`

Comment: While it's conventional to not have a space between the method name and the parameters on the invocation, their presence or absence makes no difference in behavior.

Comment: thank you but it still can't

Comment: The space between the method name and the parentheses is not an error